# Kubernetes Ingress controller dual authorization header for oauth proxy

Tags: kubernetes, oauth, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following use case:

- An http backend application running behind an oauth proxy
- An OAuth proxy that authenticates users before authorizing access to the backend application

In some cases the application behind the proxy has another authorization method that also needs to be verified.
Accessing through a browser seems to work fine as soon as I'm logged in into the oauth proxy... however, using CLI (i.e: curl) it doesn't work because I need somehow to pass 2 different authorization headers

After some reading I thought about sending 2 headers:

- Proxy-Authorization
- Authorization

The `proxy-authorization` needs to be sent to the oauth proxy, and the `authorization` is sent to the application.

For that I would add an `auth-snippet` setting the Authorization for the `auth-url` authentication and set the Authorization with the value of `Proxy-Authorization`

Something like that:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://oauth.mydomain.net/oauth2/start?rd=https://myapplication.mydomain.net
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://oauth.mydomain.net/oauth2/auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_proxy_authorization;
```

And then set the `Authorization` to the `Authorization` header on the `configuration-snippet`

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Authorization "$http_authorization";
```

Well, it doesn't work, I'm still redirected to the oauth page to login with a 302

I also tried using `$proxy_authorization` instead of `$http_proxy_authorization` and tried setting `proxy_pass_request_headers on`.

Any clue on what I can do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using cookies instead of a dual header:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: FOOBAR" -b "_oauth2_proxy=<MYCOOKIE>" https://myapplication.mydomain.net/
```